# How to Enable multiple telnet sessions same time in a single kali linux pc

Tags: kali-linux

I am doing telnet to my kali linux pc from other PC , but my kali linux pc is allowing me to open only one single session at a time. It is not allowing multiple sessions. For another session you have to close existing session and then it is allowing another session. Can anyone suggest me what to do so that it will allow multiple telnet session in single PC.

Comment: What telnet daemon are you using?

Comment: telnet daemon is xinetd 
And I am logging with root each time